# Elegant way so access a `belongs_to` -> `has_many` relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app, an user `belongs_to` a customer, and a customer `has_many` `construction_sites`. So when I want to show the `current_user` only his `construction_sites`, I have multiple possibilities of which none is elegant:

```
@construction_sites = ConstructionSite.where(customer: current_user.customer)
```

This works and looks good, except for the case that the user is not yet associated with a customer. Then, I get a `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column construction_sites.customer does not exist` error.

```
@construction_sites = ConstructionSite.where(customer_id: current_user.customer_id)
```

This seems to work fine on first sight, but again for the case that the user is not yet associated with a customer `current_user.customer_id` is `nil` and `ConstructionSite.where(customer_id: nil)` gets called which selects all (or all unassigned?) sites, which is not what I want.

#### `unless...`

```
unless current_user.customer.nil?
  @construction_sites = ConstructionSite.where(customer: current_user.customer)
else
  @construction_sites = []
end
```

Well this works, but does not look nice.

```
ConstructionSite.joins(customer: :users).where('users.id' => current_user.id)
```

works but does not look nice.

So, what is the most elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: It seems 'Unless' is the elegant way for me.And it does look nice :)

Comment: Actually, I would swap the unless for an if.  Using `unless/else` can get tough to read.  The double negative.  So something like `if current_user.customer.present? ... else ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using delegate keyword. Add this to your user model.

```
delegate :construction_sites, to: :customer, allow_nil: true
```

After that you can use statements like

```
current_user.construction_sites
```

Which I find the most elegant of all options.

Comment: This seems to work fine on first sight, but again for the case that the user is not yet associated with a customer current_user.customer_id is nil and `current_user.construction_sites` is `nil` which lets my `@sites.each ..` throw an error. But I guess I have to build in an `if @sites.nil?` anyways in the view..

Comment: Well I'm not able to figure out a way to fix it. One thing I can suggest is wherever you are assigning @sites, assign it like "@sites = current_user.connection_sites || []"

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_construction_sites
  @construction_sites = []
  @construction_sites = current_user.customer.construction_sites if current_user.customer.present?
  @construction_sites
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about moving your logic to a named scope and putting in a guard clause?

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    @construction_sites = ConstructionSite.for(current_user)
  end
end

class ConstructionSite < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for(user)
    return [] if user.customer.blank?
    where(customer: user.customer)
  end
end
```